Hide bars and values on X-Axis in case there is no value

I have a list of some dates and values as you can see in Column A and Column B. 
In the list there are values for some dates missing.
Now I want to that in the chart these dates are not displayed as long as the value is empty (as you can see in the chart with title Expected Result).
What do I need to change to make it work?

NOTE:

I have tried to go with =NA() but it did not work. 
One option could be to hide/group the rows. However, it can happen anytime that the values for these dates are not 0 anymore and I do not want to adjust the hiding/grouping each time the data changes.


You can automate hiding / unhiding the rows. Another option is to FILTER the data you want and create the graph from the filtered data.

Does it intentional that you change the dates in the expecting result? Seems has no sense

Got the filter bit to work with an additional step (check below), credits to this vid though.

If you have place for 2 helper columns, you could do:
=FILTER(A1:Bx,B1:Bx<>"")

Where x in Bx is replaced by your last row number.
=FILTER(A1:B5,B1:B5<>"")

In your case, however, you have to change the cell format to dates again for the first column.
Now next up, go to Axis formatting, select the rights most option (the 3bars), on Options for axis choose text axis

Time series are always shown with gaps, so you will first have to change your dates into text. The simplest way to do this is to insert an extra column with =TEXT(A1,"dd-mm-yy") in it.
Add a chart with only the new column and the values. Then add an Autofilter to your data, and uncheck the blank item in the value column.
